# How to get an item from a list by its property, and then use it's other property?

Tags: c#, list, xna

```
class Node
{
    int number;
    Vector2 position;
    public Node(int number, Vector2 position)
    {
        this.number = number;
        this.position = position;
    }
}
```

---

```
List<Node>nodes = new List<Node>();
```

---

```
for (int i = 0; i < nodes.Count; i++) //basically a foreach
{
    // Here i would like to find each node from the list, in the order of their numbers, 
    // and check their vectors
}
```

So, as the code pretty much tells, i am wondering how i can

1. find a specific node from the list, specifically one with the attribute "numbers" being i (Eg going through all of them in the order of their "number" attribute).
2. check its other attribute

Have tried:

```
nodes.Find(Node => Node.number == i);

Node test = nodes[i];
place = test.position
```

they cant apparently access node.number / node.position due to its protection level.

Also the second one has the problem that the nodes have to be sorted first.

Also looked at [this question](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/5b7418cd-1473-42d2-89bb-6f8c14d21270/c-list-how-to-read-the-data?forum=csharpgeneral)

but [] solution is in the "Tried" caterology, foreach solution doesn't seem to work for custom classes.

I'm a coding newbie (Like 60 hours), so don't

1. Explain in a insanely hard way.
2. Say i am dumb for not knowing a this basic thing.

Thanks!

Comment: An `attribute` is something else in C#, what you mean is a class variable or a property. This can maybe help you get some help on existing content found by Googling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would add [properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9fsa0sw.aspx) for `Number` and `Position`, making them available to outside users (currently their [access modifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173121.aspx) is `private`):

```
class Node
{
    public Node(int number, Vector2 position)
    {
        this.Number = number;
        this.Position = position;
    }

    public int Number { get; private set; }
    public Vector2 Position { get; private set; }
}
```

Now your original attempt should work:

```
nodes.Find(node => node.Number == i);
```

However, it sounds like sorting the `List<Node>` and then accessing by index would be faster. You would be sorting the list once and directly indexing the list vs looking through the list on each iteration for the item you want.

Comment: I think using Linq's `Find` function is not optimal if he uses it in the `for` loop. You could update your answer to reflect the fact that Linq can replace the `for`. Just my 2 cents.

Comment: @Bun: Updated to prefer sorting + iterating. Assuming he or she wants to retrieve each item by `Number` and do some processing, I'm not sure how LINQ really helps here

Answer (score 0):

```
List<Node> SortNodes(List<Node> nodes)
{
   List<Node> sortedNodes = new List<Node>();
   int length = nodes.Count; // The length gets less and less every time, but we still need all the numbers!
   int a = 0; // The current number we are looking for


   while (a < length)
   {
      for (int i = 0; i < nodes.Count; i++)
      {
         // if the node's number is the number we are looking for, 
         if (nodes[i].number == a)
         {
            sortedNodes.Add(list[i]); // add it to the list
            nodes.RemoveAt(i); // and remove it so we don't have to search it again.
            a++; // go to the next number
            break; // break the loop
         }
      }
   }

   return sortedNodes;
}
```

This is a simple sort function. You need to make the `number` property `public` first.
It will return a list full of nodes in the order you want to.
Also: The searching goes faster as more nodes are added to the sorted nodes list.

Make sure you that all nodes have a different number! Otherwise it would get stuck in an infinite loop!